# How to prevent applications from accessing github

Tags: github

How to prevent applications, like Visual Studio, from Pushing changes to github.  There is a PC at my previous place of employment that is linked with my github account.  I no longer have access to this PC. Is there a way from https://github.com/ to block all (connected applications) or (disconnect applications that are connected) to my github repos, so they cannot (Push) changes to my github account??

Comment: Depends on how it is connected, but I would think if you go to Settings > Password and authentication, then look under Sessions, you can press Revoke Access on the session where your work computer is logged in. This will log it out, so someone would have to have your password to get back in.

Comment: It seems like (Sessions) only show web browsers that have connected to github?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your Github password, it should prevent anyone from your old work being able to alter your work without having that new password, consider also adding two-factor auth.  You also neet to go to your account setting on the Github and scroll down to the integrations header and click on applications.  From there activate the Authorized OAuth Apps tab, revoke away.

Comment: I would have thought this (changing my login password on GitHub) would have done it but, I changed my (login password on Github) and now. .  folks at my previous job are still able to see, clone Push etc to and from GitHub through Visual Studio 2022 on my old PC?

Comment: On GitHub -Navigating (Settings)-(Integrations)-(Applications)-(Authorized OAuth Apps) tab.  That did it. Thanks Paul!